# Angularjs model not updating inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using nested ng-repeat to cycle inside properties of an array of objects and binding the model of the objects' values to inputs.
The problem is that when the values inside the inputs change, the model doesn't update.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = [{
    "user": "*US/",
    "lowFare": "*TP/<amount>/S<segment>/P<passenger>",
    "fullFare": "*PR/<amount>/S<segment>/P<passenger>",
    "selectedReason": "*REA/"
  }, {
    "user": "US/",
    "selectedReason": "REA/"
  }];
  vm.description = {
    "user": "User",
    "lowFare": "Lowest fare *",
    "fullFare": "Fare without restrictions *",
    "selectedReason": "Reason for applying the fare"
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-controller="main as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="block in ctrl.data">
      <h4 align="center">block number {{$index}}</h4>
      <table align="center">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in block" align="center">
          <td><span>{{ctrl.description[key]}}: &emsp;</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input ng-model="value" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h3 align="center">
          <br/>Modify something and see that the model doesn't change: &emsp;
          <br/>
          </h3>
    <p>
      {{ctrl.data}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kitra/qtxx9y35/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change   ng-model="value" to ng-model="block[key]" and you will get the job done.

I´m not sure, but I guess it is related to the fact that javascript references objects and arrays, while primitive values are passed by value.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = [{
    "user": "*US/",
    "lowFare": "*TP/<amount>/S<segment>/P<passenger>",
    "fullFare": "*PR/<amount>/S<segment>/P<passenger>",
    "selectedReason": "*REA/"
  }, {
    "user": "US/",
    "selectedReason": "REA/"
  }];
  vm.description = {
    "user": "User",
    "lowFare": "Lowest fare *",
    "fullFare": "Fare without restrictions *",
    "selectedReason": "Reason for applying the fare"
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-controller="main as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="block in ctrl.data">
      <h4 align="center">block number {{$index}}</h4>
      <table align="center">
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in block" align="center">
          <td><span>{{ctrl.description[key]}}: &emsp;</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input ng-model="block[key]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <h3 align="center">
          <br/>Modify something and see that the model doesn't change: &emsp;
          <br/>
          </h3>
    <p>
      {{ctrl.data}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it's the second time I ask a question on this site and find out it's a problem related to js reference, silly me! I tried using 'model="ctrl.data[block][key]' and variations of that, it didn't work and I didn't think to use 'block[key]'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "ng-model" attribute like this:

```
<input ng-model="block[key]" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mladenplavsic/qtxx9y35/51/